# Results not filtering by language

Tags: solr, content-search

I have an item which has 2 language versions - English & Chinese.
This Search query is returning both versions when the expected is only English.

Not passing the `languageCode` so by default it is `en`.
Is it the logic on how I'm building the predicate.

```
public BaseSearchResult<ProductSearchResultItem> GetSearchResult(string searchIndexName, string searchTerm, string tagId, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var query = GetSearchQuery(searchTerm, tagId, pageNumber, pageSize);
            BaseSearchResult<ProductSearchResultItem> result = searchService.GetSearchResults<ProductSearchResultItem>(searchIndexName, query);
            return result;
        }

        private IQueryable<ProductSearchResultItem> GetSearchQuery(string searchTerm, string tagId, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var predicate = GetSearchPredicate(searchTerm, tagId);
            IQueryable<ProductSearchResultItem> query = searchService.GetSearchQuery<ProductSearchResultItem>(Constants.SearchIndexes.Products, predicate);

            /// Apply pagination 
            query = query.Page((pageNumber - 1), pageSize);
            
            return query;
        }

private Expression<Func<ProductSearchResultItem, bool>> GetSearchPredicate(string searchTerm, string tagId, string languageRegionalIsoCode = "en")
        {
            Item productDetailsTemplateItem = SitecoreUtility.GetItem(Templates.ProductDetailsPage.ID);
            string productDetailsTemplateName = productDetailsTemplateItem != null ? productDetailsTemplateItem.Name : string.Empty;

            /// Initialize queries with True for AND queries and False for OR queries
            var andPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ProductSearchResultItem>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productDetailsTemplateName))
            {
                /// get only product pages of the specified language
                andPredicate = andPredicate.And(x => x.TemplateName.Equals(productDetailsTemplateName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                    
                ///get items of specified language
                andPredicate = andPredicate.And(x => x.Language.Equals(languageRegionalIsoCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                /// get only active items
                andPredicate = andPredicate.And(x => x.IsActive);

                ///filter by searchTerm
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
                {
                    andPredicate = andPredicate.And(x => x.Title.Like(searchTerm, 0.75f));

                    foreach (var t in searchTerm.Split(' '))
                    {
                        var tempTerm = t;
                        andPredicate = andPredicate.Or(p => p.Title.MatchWildcard(tempTerm + "*").Boost(5.5f));
                        andPredicate = andPredicate.Or(p => p.Title.MatchWildcard(tempTerm + "*"));
                        andPredicate = andPredicate.Or(p => p.Title.Equals(tempTerm));
                    }
                }

                ///filter by tag
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tagId))
                {
                    Guid tagGuid = new Guid(tagId);
                    andPredicate = andPredicate.And(x => x.Tags.Contains(tagGuid));
                }
            }            

            return andPredicate;
        }
```

This is the query in Search.log

> INFO  Solr Query - ?q=(((((_templatename:("Product Details Page") AND
> _language:("en")) AND is_active_b:("True")) AND title_t:(claire~0.75)) OR (title_t:(claire*))^5.5 OR title_t:(claire*) OR title_t:("claire"))
> AND tags_sm:("8f44b11cd2fd4d10b43ed16b847b4f9b")) AND
> *val*:__boost&start=0&rows=3&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(stratum_products_master_index)&wt=xml

`claire` is the "Title" of the item.

Comment: What is the query sent to Solr?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have updated my question with the log entry now. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue while adding search term predicate to your query.

You just have your main query and you add `OR Title Like SearchTerm OR ...` so it's enough that title contains search term and none of the other conditions is needed to evaluate to `true`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
{
    andPredicate = andPredicate.And(x => x.Title.Like(searchTerm, 0.75f));

    foreach (var t in searchTerm.Split(' '))
    {
        var tempTerm = t;
        andPredicate = andPredicate.Or(p => p.Title.MatchWildcard(tempTerm + "*").Boost(5.5f));
        andPredicate = andPredicate.Or(p => p.Title.MatchWildcard(tempTerm + "*"));
        andPredicate = andPredicate.Or(p => p.Title.Equals(tempTerm));
    }
}
```

Instead it should be:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
{
    var titlePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ProductSearchResultItem>();
    titlePredicate = titlePredicate.Or(x => x.Title.Like(searchTerm, 0.75f));

    foreach (var t in searchTerm.Split(' '))
    {
        var tempTerm = t;
        titlePredicate = titlePredicate.Or(p => p.Title.MatchWildcard(tempTerm + "*").Boost(5.5f));
        titlePredicate = titlePredicate.Or(p => p.Title.MatchWildcard(tempTerm + "*"));
        titlePredicate = titlePredicate.Or(p => p.Title.Equals(tempTerm));
    }

    andPredicate = andPredicate.And(titlePredicate);
}
```